# How to properly return error from createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to return the error inside of my createAsyncThunk axios response. Im not able to  trigger .catch in the caller dispatch if axios returns an error.

How can I get .catch to catch the error thrown by createAsyncThunk?

cars.store.js

```
export const getCars = createAsyncThunk(
  'cars/getCars',
  async (payload, { rejectWithValues, dispatch }) => {
    return axios.get('/cars')
      .then((res) => res.data))
      .catch((err) => rejectWithValues(err))
    }
)
const cars = createSlice({
  name: 'cars',
  initialState: {
    loading: false
    cars: []
  },
  reducers: {
    ...
    setLoading(state, action) {
      state.loading = action.payload
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getCars.pending, (state) => { state.loading = true })
      .addCase(getCars.rejected, (state) => { state.loading = false })
      .addCase(getCars.fulfilled, (state, action) => { state.cars = action.payload })
    ...
  }
})
```

caller:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getCars())
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('This wont print')
  })
})
```

AFAIK, the .catch inside the createAsyncThunk will be caught by .rejected inside extraReducers. I want to throw this error to the caller without having to keep track of a separate `error` property inside my slice. Because I will have to then reset error, set error, and it just seems like a hassle. I got this working utilizing an error property, and having the caller check it to see if the request had an error, but I would prefer handling everything through .catch in the caller.

Comment: Use `unwrap` to throw the error in catch block

Comment: Just FYI, you also have a typo in your code, `rejectWithValues` is undefined. The correct function to destructure and call with an error value to return is `rejectWithValue`.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out why I was getting typeerror in .catch when calling this thunk. This solved the issue I mentioned in Yuvaraj's solution.